# The differences between BNF and JSGF in NLP?

Tags: nlp, language-model

I wonder what the differences are between the [BNF](http://matt.might.net/articles/grammars-bnf-ebnf/)(Backus-Naur Form) and [JSGF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSGF)(Java Speech Grammar Format)? The former is a kind of context-free grammar taught in [CS224](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs224n/cs224n.1162/handouts/cgw/cgw-instructions.pdf), but I learned that the latter is also being used. Could anyone tell me which one is better and what are their differences?

Answer (score 1):

BNF (Backus normal form) is a general framework that can be adopted to a variety of contexts.

JSGF stands for Java Speech Grammar Format, thus is designed to work the Java programming language.

If I wanted to leverage a larger community of knowledge and have my work compatible with as many systems as possible, I would use BNF. If I was coding in Java, I would use JSGF.